# What is the essential idea of Kanban (for software development)?

Tags: kanban

What is the essential idea of Kanban and how does it improve the development process of a software development team (developers, designers, testers, technical writers, devops, manager, customer's representative, etc)?

Comment: can you provide us with case study where you want to use kanban with, so that we can provide you with kanban essential idea and how it may match your need, if it is applicable

Comment: I'd vote to close this question as it's answered in [What is Kanban](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/3305/430) and [What is the ongoing value of the Kanban board to the developers as opposed to management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/26262/430). I'll leave it open to allow the community to close vote, though.

Comment: Entire books are written on this topic, making it too broad. Please narrow the scope of your question, including context about a concrete problem you’re currently facing.

Comment: Entire books are written on Kanban, but I'm just asking about the essential idea Kanban is based on. This question can't be more focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the heart of Kanban is the desire to improve the effectiveness of a process.

To do this it focuses on:

- Visualisation - making it clear what is going on
- Measurement - using metrics to provide feedback and make issues visible
- Optimisation - tweaking a process and seeing if it makes things better

It is a lightweight framework, in that it does not specify a great deal about project management, engineering, etc. As such, it is relatively easy to adopt for an existing team.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Barnaby Golden! But I can't say that it explains the essence of Kanban. All that you said can equally well be applied to Scrum.